# What is a flow table? Openflow

Tags: routing, network, networking

As question asks. What is a flow table? How is it different from forwarding table?

[This](http://etherealmind.com/defining-flow-forwarding-instead-switching-routing/) link says:

> Switching = forwarding by destination MAC
> Routing = forwarding by destination IP
> Forwarding = Forwarding by Flow.

and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xLQHld3fPI) gives idea that a flow table is a forwarding table based on rules decided by controller. Not like forwarding based on IP or MAC.

If I am wrong correct me or add useful comments.

Answer (score 1):

As the links in the question suggest, flow-table is a broad term. A forwarding table uses IP address or MAC addresses to decide the next hop for the packet.

But a flow table may use any of the information within the packet to decide the next hop for it e.g. incoming switch port, TCP port/IP address (src or dst), VLAN tag etc.

> A flow is defined as all the packets matching a flow-entry
>   in a switch’s flow-table. Flow entries are quite general, and
>   resemble ACL entries found in firewalls—although here they
>   can include fields from layers 2, 3 and 4.
>
> (from *Implementing an OpenFlow Switch on the NetFPGA
>   platform* by *J. Naous et al*)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bill Lander](https://www.linkedin.com/in/bill-lander-04212422?trk=people-guest_people_search-card), [flushing Flow Table](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/mobility.py#L127) in Mininet/OpenFlow looks like clearing Address Resolution Protocol in OSI model L3 network switch. You may look into ARP document.

I haven't tested it though.

Reference:
     [Flow Table](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/5940/5200-1028b_openflow_cg/content/491966856.htm)
     [The instruction of "dpctl" function](http://ranosgrant.cocolog-nifty.com/openflow/dpctl.8.html) - flushing Flow Table